# GSON InstanceCreator set data

Tags: java, json, interface, gson

I have a little problem.
I stored some data in a json-file, and it works fine.
But if i try to retrieval this data there is a problem with the interfaces of the object i am trying to create.
This is a simplified version of my class

```
public class MyObject{ 

//this is a interface 
public Vector3Int position;
...}
```

Ok, GSON can't create interfaces without a consturctor, so i create this class:

```
public class VectorInstanceCreator implements InstanceCreator<Vector3Int >{

  @Override
   public Vector3Int createInstance(Type arg0) {
        return new VectorImpl();
   }

}
```

And i use it in this way:

```
    ...
    GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
    gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Vector3Int.class, new new VectorInstanceCreator());
    Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
    gson.fromJson(myJsonString, MyObject.class);
    ...
```

So, it works but the values in my json file is for example:

```
"position": {"x": 1.0, "y": 1.0,"z": 0.0}
```

but each value in the Java-Object-Vector is 0. So it means, gson use just the given consturctor of my VectorInstanceCreator class, but is not setting the values of the JSON-File/Object.

How do i set this values by using a interface with InstanceCreator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple solution on http://technology.finra.org/code/serialize-deserialize-interfaces-in-java.html for my problem. With the template InterfaceAdapter, each class name will stored additional in the json file. So the retrieval method, to restore the classes know the exact class and not just the interface. This works well for me.